# Windows Form with Dropped Down ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

After dropping down the ComboBox on the Windows Form, I click on the Minimize button, but the ComboBox is collapsing instead of the Form minimizing. The ComboBox has a DropDownStyle ComboBoxStyle.DropDown.
Is any way to push the Form to behave correctly?

[image]

If I click on "Minimize" button on the right-up corner of the window (the button with the horizontal bar third from the right), the ComboBox will be collapsed instead of the window minimizing. But I want to close the window.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: It's a focus issue.  It takes that click to trigger the combo box to lose focus and collapse.  You're trying to get two for the price of one.  You'll probably have to go the `WndProc` route to get over that hump.

Comment: It's also really hard to imagine this would be an issue for your users.

Comment: It is already the issue for my users :). I hoped it can be done with assigning the properties of Form, ComboBox, etc., but now I see that I will use surgical methods...